# How to change csv into dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a csv file with columns as a list I want to turn into a dictionary with column headers as keys and the rest of the column as a list the value. I want to do it without importing.

How would I turn this:

```
[
['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'],
['1', 'a', 'd', 'g', 'j'],
['2', 'b', 'e', 'h', 'k'],
['3', 'c', 'f', 'I', 'l']
]
```

Into this:

```
{
'col1': ['1', '2', '3'],
'col2': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
'col3': ['d', 'e', 'f'],
'col4': ['g', 'h', 'I'],
'col5': ['j', 'k', 'l']
}
```

Thanks.  I could also use a 2D array instead of the initial list?

Comment: "I want to do it without importing." Why is that? What do you actually have as input – a CSV (i.e. *text*) or a list of lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your list of lists, you can use the built-in [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function and a bit of syntactic sugar to split up your data:

```py
data = [
['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'],
['1', 'a', 'd', 'g', 'j'],
['2', 'b', 'e', 'h', 'k'],
['3', 'c', 'f', 'I', 'l']
]
transformed = {key: value for key, *value in zip(*data)}
```

gives

```
{
'col1': ['1', '2', '3'], 
'col2': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
'col3': ['d', 'e', 'f'], 
'col4': ['g', 'h', 'I'], 
'col5': ['j', 'k', 'l']
}
```

To handle a CSV file without importing the appropriate [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module, you'll end up parsing the text yourself, essentially re-implementing existing built-in code.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [
['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'],
['1', 'a', 'd', 'g', 'j'],
['2', 'b', 'e', 'h', 'k'],
['3', 'c', 'f', 'I', 'l']]
d = []
for i in range(len(data[0])):
    d1 = []
    for j in range(len(data)):
        d1.append(data[j][i])
    d.append(d1)
transform = {}
for i in range(len(d)):
    transform[d[i][0]] = d[i][1:]
print(transform)
```